# How not to open mat-sidenav when page loads

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I've got service for mat-sidenav toggle with BehaviorSubject.

**service.ts**

```
    export class ToggleSidenavService {
       public sideNavToggleSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

       public toggle() {
          return this.sideNavToggleSubject.next(null);
       }
    }
```

**Component.html**

```
      @ViewChild('sidenav', {static: true}) public sidenav: MatSidenav;

     ngOnInit() {
        this.sidenavService.sideNavToggleSubject.subscribe(() => {
        this.sidenav.toggle();
       });
     }
```

Sidenav toggle is working fine, but it always opens when the page loads. How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you control `sideNavToggleSubject ` to open/close modal, it look always emit `null` value. Dose it means always open?

Comment: the button could toggle the sidenav open/close state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the `Sidenav` is always closed when the page loads, set the `opened` property to `false` in the HTML template.

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="false">
  Sidenav content
</mat-sidenav>
```

To programmatically close the `Sidenav`, you can call the `close()` method in `ngAfterViewInit()`, but this is not necessary if `opened` is set.

```
@ViewChild('sidenav', {static: true}) public sidenav: MatSidenav;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sidenav.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but I can see how sidenav playing closing animation after view init

Comment: @OlegShchegolev See updated answer that sets the `opened` property in the HTML template.